# Select Insert like unpivot and pivot

Tags: sql-server

Table-1:

```
kode  | 101  | 102 | 103   | 104
=================================
1234  | 100  | 200 | 300   | 400
4555  | 1200 | 130 | 14500 | 1550
5012  | 100  | 150 | 350   | 440
```

Table-2:

```
kode  | field1 | field2
=======================
1234  | 101    | 100
1234  | 102    | 200
1234  | 103    | 300
1234  | 104    | 400
4555  | 101    | 1200
4555  | 102    | 130
4555  | 103    | 14500
4555  | 104    | 1550
5012  | 101    | 100
5012  | 102    | 150
5012  | 103    | 350
5012  | 104    | 440
```

I have data in `table-1`, how to insert data from `table-1` to`table-2`
with use sql query like unpivot to pivot which dynamic by using set @cols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNPIVOT to create the dataset you want. Let's say your tables looked like this:

```
create table table1 (
    kode int,
    [101] int,
    [102] int,
    [103] int,
    [104] int
);

insert into table1 values
(1234  , 100  , 200 , 300   , 400),
(4555  , 1200 , 130 , 14500 , 1550),
(5012  , 100  , 150 , 350   , 440);
```

**Your query will look like this**

```
SELECT kode, field1, field2
FROM table1
UNPIVOT 
(
  field2 FOR field1 IN ([101], [102], [103], [104])
) AS up;
```

That will give you the desired result.

**Let's way you have a new table like this**

```
create table table2 (
    kode int,
    field1 int,
    field2 int
);
```

**Populate UNPIVOT'ed data into table2**

```
insert into table2
SELECT kode, field1, field2
FROM table1
UNPIVOT 
(
  field2 FOR field1 IN ([101], [102], [103], [104])
) AS up;

select * from table2;
```

Example: https://rextester.com/YPWG93602